# how to get the td clicked having tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `tr` with a click listener. I want to know which `td` was the one clicked:

```
<tr class ="clickingClass">
  <td> first td </td>
  <td> second td </td>
</tr>
```

```js
$(".clickingClass").on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('td');
});
```

The above shows nothing. How can I do this?

Comment: this returns all the td in the tr, I want to know wich one is clicked

Comment: `closest()` goes up the DOM only, not down it. Try using the `target` property of the `event` passed to the handler function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because `closest()` goes up the DOM, not down it.

To do what you require you could instead attach the event handler directly on the `td` elements:

```
$(".clickingClass td").on('click', function() {
    // do something with $(this)...
});
```

Alternatively you could use the `target` property of the event passed to the handler function to determine which `td` was clicked:

```
$(".clickingClass").on('click', function(e) {
    // do something with $(e.target)...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event.target` for this

```
$(".clickingClass").on('click',function(event){
    alert(event.target);
});
```

Comment: @Mujtaba Kably 2  bydefault `event.target` always give target element not listener.
If you add `event.stopPropagation` then it give listener element

Answer (score 0):

Why not bind to the `td`s instead?

```
$(".clickingClass td").on('click',function(){
   this //td
});
```